# How to approach stationarity in Hamilton mechanics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

The analogue of the action in Hamiltonian mechanics is
$$ S [ q, p] =\int_{t_1}^{t_2} [p_\alpha (t^\prime) \dot{q}_\alpha (t^\prime) - H (q_\alpha (t^\prime),p_\alpha (t^\prime),t^\prime)]d t^\prime. $$

How would one go about determine the conditions under which the action is stationary with respect to variations of the $q_\alpha, p_\alpha$? I assumed that you consider the variations $\delta q_\alpha$ and $\delta p_\alpha$ but I can't see how to deal with terms of the form $\delta p_\alpha \; \dot{q}_\alpha (t^\prime)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\delta p$, $\delta q$ are zero at $t=t_0, t_1$ so that we can ignore integrated out bits,  we have
$$
\delta S= \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \left\{\left(- \frac{d p}{dt} -\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\right)\delta q(t) +\left(\frac{dq}{dt}- \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\right)\delta p(t)\right\}dt
$$
so stationarity needs
$$
 \frac{d p}{dt} =-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\\
 \frac{d q}{dt} =+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p},
$$
i.e Hamilton's equations.

Comment: Just a further point: I used (restricting to one dimension:
$$\delta S = \int \left( (\delta p) \dot{q} + p \delta \dot{q} + ....\right) dt .$$
I am just wondering whether this is correct since I am only considering variations in $p \mbox{ and } q$? Can I have a variation in $\dot{q}$?

Comment: As always in calculus of variation $\delta \dot q= d (\delta q)/dt$. This is why you need an integration-by--parts.